# UML-Designer: Creating Fields, which include Java collections

Tags: collections, uml, uml-designer

I have a question about UML-Designer. I want to design my Java project, via the Class Diagram feature. Though i noticed, when i add in a Attribute/Field to my class. I have the issue to not be able to add in something like a Collection type. A example being List. If anyone knows how to do that, i would be really appreciative.

Thanks for the replies in advance.

Comment: what is exactely your problem ? you cannot have an attribute of type *List* because the type *List* is refused ? DId you try creating first the class *List* ? Note *List* is a *generic* so may be the tool request a `List<a-type>` rather than just `List`

Comment: did you tried to reverse a Java code having an attribute of that kind of type to see how to model it ?